# how to use Service Worker to cache cross domain resources if the response is 404?

Tags: javascript, caching, cross-domain, service-worker

w3:

> 6.2 Cross-Origin Resources and CORS¶
>           Applications tend to cache items that come from a CDN or other origin.
>   It is possible to request many of them directly using `<script>, <img>, <video>`
>   and `<link>` elements. It would be hugely limiting if this sort of runtime
>   collaboration broke when offline.
>   Similarly, it is possible to XHR many sorts of off-origin resources when
>   appropriate CORS headers are set.
>
> ServiceWorkers enable this by allowing Caches to fetch and cache off-origin
>   items. Some restrictions apply, however. First, unlike same-origin resources
>   which are managed in the Cache as Response objects with the type attribute set
>   to "basic", the objects stored are Response objects with the type attribute set
>   to "opaque". Responses typed "opaque" provide a much less expressive API than
>   Responses typed "basic"; the bodies and headers cannot be read or set, nor many
>   of the other aspects of their content inspected. They can be passed to
>   event.respondWith(r) method in the same manner as the Responses typed "basic",
>   but cannot be meaningfully created programmatically. These limitations are
>   necessary to preserve the security invariants of the platform. Allowing Caches
>   to store them allows applications to avoid re-architecting in most cases.

I have set the CORS header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://xxx.xx.x.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
```

but I still get an "opaque" response and I cannot ensure the code is 200.
If I cache these unsuccessful responses, it will cause some problem.

For example, a chum of network causes a 404 to the cross domain resources,
and I cache it, then I will always use this 404 cache response even thongth when
the network problem is corrected. The same-origin resource do not have this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `mode` of a `Request` (allegedly) [defaults to `"no-cors"`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode). (I say "allegedly" because I believe I've seen situations in which an implicitly created `Request` used in `fetch()` results in a CORS-enabled `Response`.)

So you should be explicit about opting in to CORS if you know that your server supports it:

```
var corsRequest = new Request(url, {mode: 'cors'});
fetch(corsRequest).then(response => ...); // response won't be opaque.
```

Given a properly configured remote server, a CORS-enabled `Request` will result in a `Response` that has a [`type` of `"cors"`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-type). Unlike an `"opaque"` `Response`, a `"cors"` `Response` will expose the underlying `status`, `body`, etc.

Comment: waoooooooooooooo~~~~ Thank you very very much!!! It is really working for me. mua~~

Comment: The question here is how you originally make the requests that are you tunneling through the service worker. If those use "no-cors", that's what you'll get. `new Request("x").mode` returns "cors" though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to detect it.

For security reasons, it's explicitly not allowed: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/14.