# PreloadJS and Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, preloadjs, cacheapi

I am trying to use service worker with PreloadJS. I have cached the images required and then loading them using the [`caches.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/match) function.

When I try to load the image with jquery it works fine, but on loading with preloadJS it gives the following error

> The FetchEvent for "someurl" resulted in a network error response: an "opaque" response was used for a request whose type is not no-cors

Although if I load any other image that isn't cached, PreloadJS loads that image properly. The problem is occuring only when I use `caches.match`.

What might be the reason for this ?

Load Image using preloadjs

```
var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue({ crossOrigin: "Anonymous" });

function loadImageUsingPreload() {

  preload.on('complete', completed);

  preload.loadFile({ id: 'someid', src: 'someurl', crossOrigin: true })

};

function completed() {
  var image = preload.getResult("shd");
  document.body.append(image);
};
```

Load Image using jquery

```
function loadImageUsingJquery() {
  jQuery("#image").attr('src', 'someurl');
};
```

Service Worker fetch event

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {

      if (!response) {
        console.log('fetching...' + event.request.url);
        return fetch(event.request);
      };
      console.log("response", response);
      return response;
    }));
});
```

The response object when I load using PreloadJS or jQuery:

> Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}

Comment: did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626269/how-to-use-service-worker-to-cache-cross-domain-resources-if-the-response-is-404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the mistake ,

Actually during `cache.put` I was modifying the request object's mode to `'no-cors'` if the origin were not the same.

Now during a fetch event, the event's request object had property `'cors'` because it was a cross-origin request.

This difference of value of `mode` was causing the fetch error.

Service worker install event:

```
var request = new Request(value);
var url = new URL(request.url);

if (url.origin != location.origin) {
    request = new Request(value, { mode: 'no-cors' });
}

return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    var cachedCopy = response.clone();
    return cache.put(request, cachedCopy);
});
```

I changed it to :

```
var request = new Request(value);
var url = new URL(request.url);

return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    var cachedCopy = response.clone();
    return cache.put(request, cachedCopy);
});
```

I have to use the first method for saving cdn's because second method is not working for them and vice-versa for my images hosted on cloudfront .

I will post the reason when I find why this is happening.